# Помогите с рекурсией

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Задача - сделать функцию для поиска по объекту сложной вложенности, нужно найти значение ячейки с именем "treasure" вот пример проверки:

```js
const obj = {
  a: ["qwe", 124],
  b: {
    c: ["zaaaz"],
    d: [{ treasure: 1755 }],
    e: "treasure"
  },
  f: {
    g: "key"
  },
  h: ["qwe", 124]
};
console.log(findTreasure(obj));
```

Набросал приблизительное решение, но не выходит вернуть искомое значение

```js
function findTreasure(obj, a = 0, searchingName = "treasure") {
  for (let m in obj) {
    if (obj[searchingName]) {
      a = obj[searchingName];
    } else if (typeof obj[m] === "object") findTreasure(obj[m], a);
  }
  return a;
}
```

Подскажите, где накосячил

Comment: А по условию d или e надо найти?

Comment: Sorry, сейчас поправлю условие

Comment: Так у тебя она в d даже не войдёт.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В коде есть несколько проблем:

1. если значение найдено - продолжается проход по остальным полям, хотя можно было выйти
2. не возвращается результат рекурсии
3. не проверяется результат рекурсии

Если исправить эти проблемы можно получить следующий код:

```js
function findTreasure(obj, searchingName = "treasure") {
  if (obj[searchingName]) {
    return obj[searchingName];
  }
  for (let m in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[m] === "object") {
      var val = findTreasure(obj[m], searchingName);
      if (val) return val;
    }
  }
}

const obj = {
  a: ["qwe", 124],
  b: {
    c: ["zaaaz"],
    d: [{
      treasure: 1755
    }],
    e: "treasure"
  },
  f: {
    g: "key"
  },
  h: ["qwe", 124]
};
console.log(findTreasure(obj));
```